# What would be valid starting conditions to pass to fitgmdist?

Tags: matlab, octave, gaussian, mixture-model

I am trying to use the fitgmdist function from the statistics package in Octave. It works when I let it use the default k++ method for finding initial parameters. However, the results are not consistent and sometimes just plane wrong. That is why I wanted to be able to pass initial values for the means based on looking at the histograms. But for some reason the function won't accept them. The error I keep ending up with is the following:

```
error: fitgmdist: invalid start parameter
error: called from
    fitgmdist at line 202 column 9
    curve_fitting at line 78 column 17
```

curve_fitting is just the name of my script.
I am trying to use the following code for the function:

```
nbOrientations = 2;
initial_orientations = [38.0; 18.0]; % #values here should match nbOrientations
initial_weights = ones(1,nbOrientations)/nbOrientations;
initial_Sigma = ones(1,1,nbOrientations);
start = struct('mu',initial_orientations,'Sigma',initial_Sigma,'ComponentProportion',initial_weights)
GMModel_Theta = fitgmdist(Angle_Theta, nbOrientations,'Start', start,'RegularizationValue',0.0001)
```

My data is just a 700ish by 1 array.

I checked my struct and it seems to me that it satisfies the requirements I could find in the matlab/octave documentation. I am all out of ideas on how to fix this. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

**EDIT:**
I managed to test my script in matlab on someone else's computer and there is just worked. It seems to me that this is an issue with Octave.

Comment: Hi Sander, which version of the statistics package do you have? I recently submitted a bug relating to version 1.4.2 which may be relevant: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=59386 . Effectively there was a typo in the source code of fitgmdist, (`ComponentProprition` instead of `ComponentProportion`!) If you can't wait for the updated package to be released, you can edit it yourself as per the fix: https://sourceforge.net/p/octave/statistics/ci/f5d650fdcc7c1988abdef5aee1ef5ac8ef6c29b4/ (effectively correcting the typo).

Comment: Hi Tasos,

I am indeed using version 1.4.2. You got me pointed in the right direction.

Comment: However, it seems that there is still an error thrown on line 199 that shouldn't be thrown. I commented out the error throwing bit and then it just ran like it should.

Comment: you may be on to something. Lines 197-199 seem to check if the data and struct components are arranged in a "compatible" way, i.e. rows as components, and columns as dimensions. If you are sure your inputs are arranged correctly and that check is buggy, then I would encourage you to contribute to the project by creating a bug on the [bug tracker](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/bugs.html) :)   I wouldn't simply comment out those lines though; it's better to ensure the checks are performed correctly, than to ignore them and end up with possibly misleading results!

Comment: In any case, since this was the right issue, I will create an answer below if you don't mind, for the sake of future readers possibly having the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting the discussion in the comments to an answer for the sake of future readers. There are *two* issues here:

---

The first is that you are encountering a **known bug** in octave's statistics package `v1.4.2`, which was [reported here](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=59386), and has been [fixed](https://sourceforge.net/p/octave/statistics/ci/f5d650fdcc7c1988abdef5aee1ef5ac8ef6c29b4/) for the upcoming version (which, at the point of writing this answer, has yet to be released).

If you'd like to apply the fix yourself rather than wait for the next release, effectively correct the typo on line `194` (from `'ComponentProprition'` to `'ComponentProportion'` ), and comment out the unnecessary check in lines `204`-`206`.

---

The second is that **you have also come across an unreported bug**. I'm converting your code to a full testcase below to demonstrate the issue (I changed the values *slightly* to match my input):

```
pkg load statistics

Angle_Theta          = [ 30 + 10 * randn(1, 10),  60 + 10 * randn(1, 10) ].';
nbOrientations       = 2;
initial_orientations = [38.0; 18.0];   % values here should match nbOrientations
initial_weights      = ones( 1, nbOrientations ) / nbOrientations;
initial_Sigma        = 10 * ones( 1, 1, nbOrientations );

start = struct( 'mu'                 , initial_orientations,
                'Sigma'              , initial_Sigma       ,
                'ComponentProportion', initial_weights        )

GMModel_Theta = fitgmdist( Angle_Theta          , 
                           nbOrientations       ,
                           'Start'              , start ,
                           'RegularizationValue', 0.0001   )
```

Line `197`, tries to ensure that there are no mismatched dimensions. Unfortunately in doing so, it seems to disregard that Sigma may not be shared, so the check fails when sigma contains more than 2 dimensions (i.e. when the 3rd dimension represents the number of components).

I modified the code, changing `size(Sigma)` into `size(Sigma,1)`, i.e. effectively making the check against only the *rows* of `Sigma`, assuming (naively) that the remaining dimensions of `Sigma` are fine. This enables the check to pass (while still being a useful check), and the code now runs as expected, giving the following output:

```
Gaussian mixture distribution with 2 components in 1 dimension(s)
Clust 1: weight 0.450954
        Mean: 60.839
        Variance:45.190
Clust 2: weight 0.549046
        Mean: 32.3048
        Variance:98.217
AIC=174.207 BIC=179.186 NLogL=82.1037 Iter=84 Cged=1 Reg=0.0001
```

Since you've helped uncover another bug, it would be useful to [report it to the octave bug tracker](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/bugs).

I'm happy to do it on your behalf; I'm equally happy if you'd like to take this opportunity to engage with the octave / open-source community and contribute the bug report yourself<sup>1</sup>. Let me know :)

---

<sub>1. If you do, would you mind commenting a link to the bug report here for reference :)</sub>

Comment: Feel free to make the bug report yourself.

Comment: @Sander submitted as [bug #59804](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?59804) on the octave bug tracker.